# UIActivityIndicatorView not displaying right on UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I am writing an iOS app, and I have to display a UIAlertView with a spinner. *Sometimes*, something goes wrong when I try to add the spinner in the center of the alert, usually when there was another alert right before this one (not exactly a rule, but this is how I noticed it fails).

I partly solved this bug by delaying the creation of the spinner. Here is how I do it (*alert* is a member UIAlertView) :

This code is in viewDidLoad :

```
alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];

[alert show];

[self performSelector:@selector(addSpinner) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
```

And this one is my *addSpinner* function :

```
- (void) addSpinner{

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator2 = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator2.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);

    [indicator2 startAnimating];
    [alert addSubview:indicator2];
    [indicator2 release];
}
```

This solution is working every time, but I really don't like how it's done. Even though showing the spinner half a second after the alert pops up is not so much disturbing, there must be a better way to handle this. I am not an expert in iOS, nor am I a senior programmer, but can't I use an event ? Something like "when the alert is actually displayed, go the addSpinner function" ? I have no idea how to do this, and could not find much help on the web...

Hope someone can help me ! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD instead.

and for spinner within alert, you can use these methods.

```
-(void)startLoading
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please Wait..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
    progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [alert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];
    [progress release];
    [alert show];
}
-(void)stopLoading
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks pretty good, I may try using it. I can't mark your answer as my "accepted answer", as it doesn't really solve the problem :)

Comment: I have added some code to solve your problem, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I may have not been clear enough on my original post : at first, the spinner was moved up and on the left, when I was using `indicator2.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);` in order to set the spinner position relatively to the alert. Then, I tried the solution you wrote here (obviously in a different way, that's why I didn't notice it at first), with the position of the spinner set as "absolute" with `CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)`. I don't really like this solution either, as it may cause troubles in some situations :s

Comment: i used alert with indicator in my previous projects, but i think MBProgressHUD is much better to use, it will save your time, and has no such issues.

Answer (score 4):

Basically problem looks to be Adding UIActivityIndicator before UIAlertView is displayed. Try using UIAlertView Delegate method to add the Indicator as below.

```
//AlertView delegate methods
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alertView.bounds.size.width/2, alertView.bounds.size.height/3 * 2);

    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alertView addSubview:indicator];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the late answer, it may solve the problem, but I'm not facing it anymore, as I used MBProgressHUD.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
megaAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please wait..."
                                                         message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
[megaAlert show];
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]                                                      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
            indicator.center = CGPointMake(megaAlert.bounds.size.width / 2,                                            megaAlert.bounds.size.height - 45);
[indicator startAnimating];
[megaAlert addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];
```

To dismiss the Indicator use this code

```
[megaAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
megaAlert = nil;
[indicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what I did in the first place, without dismissing the alert... Do you think it can impact the position of the UIActivityIndicator ? I'll let you know if it works in a few minutes.

Comment: It really seems that the problem appears because the position of the UIActivityIndicator is set before the UIAlertView is displayed. I don't think dismissing the alert will solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Remember also to dismiss alert in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```