# Weird UIAlertView with UIActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c

i´ve just asked this question [Run code on background and get return code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710954/run-code-on-background-and-get-return-code)

And i used a UIAlertView with activity indicator while doing the background task, final code:

```
    -(void)isConnectedToInternet:(void (^)(BOOL))block
{
    palert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Comprobando conexión a internet" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [palert show];

    if(palert != nil) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        indicator.center = CGPointMake(palert.bounds.size.width/2, palert.bounds.size.height-45);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [palert addSubview:indicator];
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        if (block) {
            [palert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            block( ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO);
        }
    }];
```

Its same code as accepted answer with an UIAlertView, right after doing that im showing a new UIViewController that do a similar thing on ViewDidLoad.

```
    alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Descargando..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alerta show];

if(alerta != nil) {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alerta.bounds.size.width/2, alerta.bounds.size.height-45);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alerta addSubview:indicator];
}
```

I was using that same code to show UIAlertView with activity indicator a long time ago, the first alertview for check internet connection shows well, but the second not...

[image]

I really cant understand why the first show the indicator inside alerView and second shows it outside alertView if both have exactly the same code.

And that only happens after adding a first UIAlertView, before adding that it was working well.

Im really stuck on this i cant find a solution.

Anyone has some idea?

**EDIT**

Easy way solution, i just hardcode it.

And yea it seems that alert.frame is not set, maybe similar to this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408594/uiactivityindicatorview-not-displaying-right-on-uialertview?rq=1)

```
indicator.center = CGPointMake(140, 70);
```

Comment: just set indicator view frame with in alertview image

Comment: It looks like you have `CGRectZero` as `alerta.bounds` when using alert for the second time. Try to subclass `UIAlertView` and set activity indicator frame at `layoutSubviews` instead.

Comment: hi @user2260916 check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906726/how-can-i-do-uialertview-with-activity-indicator) you will solve your problem, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check `MBProgressHud` class

[UIActivityIndicatorView and MBProgressHUD](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiactivityindicatorview_mbprogresshud/) (@ mobile.tutsplus.com)

and also

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) (@ github.com)

It may help you.

Comment: UIActivityIndicator its ok for my needs i dont want to use third party code.

Comment: @Divz how is it supposed to be helpful ?

Comment: I think you should use the predefined things which can be easily to manage in this MBProgressHud class the same thing is done what ever you are creating So this will save your time.